# How to write a test that expects an error to be thrown after a $broadcast

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have an event listener with a switch statement inside it which should throw an error when the variable in question is not catered for in the switch statement.

I'm not sure how to get the error being thrown inside the listener.

**My Jasmine code**

```
describe("event listner, 'somethingChanged'", function () {

            beforeEach(function () {

                $rootScope.$broadcast('somethingChanged', broadcastObject);

                broadcastObject= {
                    name: "Hello",
                    id: 123,
                    serviceTypeIdentifier: 0
                };
            });

            it("should throw an error if the broadcastObject's service type identifier has not been catered for", function () {

                expect(function () {

                    //...this is where I need to get a hold of the error being thrown somehow.

                }).toThrow();
            });
        });
```

**Event Listener (Angular code)**

```
$scope.$on("somethingChanged", function(event, args) {
                $scope.isBusy = true;
                broadcastObject = args;

                switch (broadcastObject.serviceTypeIdentifier) {
                    case 1:
                        //blah blah
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //blah blah blah
                        break;
                    default:
                        $scope.isBusy = false;
                        throw "service type identifier of " + broadcastObject.serviceTypeIdentifier + " has not been catered for. Please verify the service ID of the object";
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move event emitting to the `expect` section, e.g

#### spec.js

```
describe('Controller: somethingChanged', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('something'));

    var $rootScope, scope;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('somethingChanged', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('throws error if service type identifier has not been provided', function () {
        expect(function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('somethingChanged', {});
        }).toThrow('service type identifier of undefined has not been catered for. Please verify the service ID of the object')
    });
});
```

It will pass test if controller will looks like:

#### controller.js

```
angular.module('something', [])
    .controller('somethingChanged', function ($scope) {
        $scope.$on("somethingChanged", function (event, args) {
            $scope.isBusy = true;

            switch (args.serviceTypeIdentifier) {
                case 1:
                    //blah blah
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //blah blah blah
                    break;
                default:
                    $scope.isBusy = false;
                    throw "service type identifier of " + args.serviceTypeIdentifier + " has not been catered for. Please verify the service ID of the object";
            }
        });
    });
```

Note: when you will study example, please take a look how argument `_$rootScope_` was assigned to variable `$rootScope`. It is part of internal AngularJS mechanism to strip all `_` signs from variable names.

Comment: Much thanks! Moving the broadcast in the expect() did the trick.